# Trouble using configparser to pass API credentials

Tags: python, ini, configparser, praw

I have a config.ini file that looks like this

```
[REDDIT]
client_id = 'myclientid23jd934g'
client_secret = 'myclientsecretjf30gj5g'
password = 'mypassword'
user_agent = 'myuseragent'
username = 'myusername'
```

When I try to use reddit's API praw like this:

```
import configparser
import praw

class redditImageScraper:
    def __init__(self, sub, limit):
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config.read('config.ini')
        self.sub = sub
        self.limit = limit
        self.reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id=config.get('REDDIT','client_id'),
                                  client_secret=config.get('REDDIT','client_secret'),
                                  password=config.get('REDDIT','password'),
                                  user_agent=config.get('REDDIT','user_agent'),
                                  username=config.get('REDDIT','username'))


    def get_content(self):
        submissions = self.reddit.subreddit(self.sub).hot(limit=self.limit)
        for submission in submissions:
            print(submission.id)

def main():
    scraper = redditImageScraper('aww', 25)
    scraper.get_content()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I get this traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "config.py", line 30, in <module>
    main()
  File "config.py", line 27, in main
    scraper.get_content()
  File "config.py", line 22, in get_content
    for submission in submissions:
  File "C:\Users\Evan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\praw\models\listing\generator.py", line 61, in __next__
    self._next_batch()
  File "C:\Users\Evan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\praw\models\listing\generator.py", line 71, in _next_batch
    self._listing = self._reddit.get(self.url, params=self.params)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\praw\reddit.py", line 454, in get
    data = self.request("GET", path, params=params)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\praw\reddit.py", line 627, in request
    method, path, data=data, files=files, params=params
  File "C:\Users\Evan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 185, in request
    params=params, url=url)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 116, in _request_with_retries
    data, files, json, method, params, retries, url)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 101, in _make_request
    params=params)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\prawcore\rate_limit.py", line 35, in call
    kwargs['headers'] = set_header_callback()
  File "C:\Users\Evan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 145, in _set_header_callback
    self._authorizer.refresh()
  File "C:\Users\Evan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\prawcore\auth.py", line 328, in refresh
    password=self._password)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\prawcore\auth.py", line 138, in _request_token
    response = self._authenticator._post(url, **data)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\prawcore\auth.py", line 31, in _post
    raise ResponseException(response)
prawcore.exceptions.ResponseException: received 401 HTTP response
```

However when I manually insert the credentials, my code runs exactly as expected. Also, if I run the line

`print(config.get('REDDIT', 'client_id'))`

I get the output `'myclientid23jd934g'` as expected.

Is there some reason that praw won't allow me to pass my credentials using configparser?

Comment: double check what you're putting in e.g. `kwargs = dict(client_id=config.get('REDDIT','client_id'),
                                  client_secret=config.get('REDDIT','client_secret'),
                                  password=config.get('REDDIT','password'),
                                  user_agent=config.get('REDDIT','user_agent'),
                                  username=config.get('REDDIT','username')); print(kwargs); praw.Reddit(**kwargs)`

Comment: @Macattack Thank you! Checking it that way showed that it had an extra set of quotations around each credential. ini files don't need quotation marks because everything gets interpreted as a string. Everything works now! Feel free to add your comment as a solution and I will select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check what your inputs to `praw.Reddit` are:

```
kwargs = dict(client_id=config.get('REDDIT','client_id'),
              client_secret=config.get('REDDIT','client_secret'),
              password=config.get('REDDIT','password'),
              user_agent=config.get('REDDIT','user_agent'),
              username=config.get('REDDIT','username'))) 
print(kwargs)
praw.Reddit(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're overcomplicating configuration here — PRAW will take care of this for you.

If you rename `config.ini` to `praw.ini`, you can replace your whole initialization with just

```
self.reddit = praw.Reddit('REDDIT')
```

This is because PRAW will look for a `praw.ini` file and parse it for you. If you want to give the section a more descriptive name, make sure to update it in the `praw.ini` as well as in the single parameter passed to `Reddit` (which specifies the section of the file to use).

See https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/configuration/prawini.html.

As this page notes, values like username and password should not have quotation marks around them. For example,

```
password=mypassword
```

is correct, but

```
password="mypassword"
```

is incorrect.

Comment: Quick question. I would like to keep the praw.ini file in a separate directory from the script itself. I am using windows and I see in the docs it says it will find the file "In the directory specified by the APPDATA environment variable (Windows)." I have a TEMP environment variable which points to ..\AppData\Local\Temp. Do I need to create a new variable called APPDATA and point it to the folder containing my praw.ini?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the specifics of Windows, but yes, it seems you have to set the APPDATA environment variable and point it to the folder that contains your `praw.ini`.